# Backup daily MYSQL using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have found a php script online, when i go to the link in my browser this script wil make an backup of my MYSQL Database and place a .SQL file into my root folder.
It works fine for me.. but i have just 1 question!!!

Is there some php code that i can add to the script it wil run automatic like every hour, day, or weekly???

this is the backup script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// DB connection
backup_tables('#','#','#','#');

/* backup the db OR just a table, make 'user' to --> '*' to get all the tables */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) 
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file
    $handle = fopen('backup/db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: it's called a cron job

Comment: create a cron job at say 12 midnight and use mysqldump command to take daily backup of data

Comment: as the above comments suggests; `cron job` is the way to go. If you have cPanel, it has a nice GUI for you to setup your `crons`

Comment: my host use **DirectAdmin**